# Help parsing this sentence

Tags: parsing

インドの文化にくわしい友達を、今度ごしょうかいします。

I have trouble parsing this sentence...

What I roughly understand:
インドの文化 seems to be indonesia's culture, but  i don't understand the function of に in the back. Or is it a place?  So it can means "In indonesia's culture festival"?

くわしい ともだちを: Do something to my well informed friend (but why the を end with comma? )

今度 sometimes / this time? 
ごしょうかいします: doing introduction? Asking reference? I'm not sure...

With all that information I have trouble finding out what the speaker is speaking about...

Comment: 今度、インドの文化にくわしい友達をしょうかします。 Do you understand this phrase? (I changed word order a bit and removed keigo but overall meaning is same)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> インドの文化 seems to be indonesia's culture

インド normally means India not Indonesia.

> くわしい ともだちを:  ...

You're right about the well-informed friend part. but the を marks that this phrase receives the action of the verb (which comes at the end).

> 今度 sometimes / this time?

in this case, means "next time"

> ごしょうかいします。  doing introduction? Asking reference? I'm not sure...

it might be easier to understand with the kanji ご紹介します. Also we can drop the ご to make it easier to understand as 紹介します

---

> インドの文化にくわしい友達を、今度ごしょうかいします。

means "next time, I will introduce you to a friend who is well-informed about India."

- As stated above インド is India.
- の makes インド as "genitive" or
  "possessive" of what follows.
- に marks the preceding phrase describing
  something with respect to what follows.
- [詳]{くわ}しい is quite a bit more
  casual than "well-informed" but I'm not really sure what would be a
  better expression.
- 友達 = friend
- を marks this entire block as related
  to the verb at the end
- 、 the comma indicates a break in grammar
  versus normal order here.
- 今度  in this case means "next time" but in
  other cases can mean "some time" or "this time"
- ご紹介します is a polite
  way of saying "introduce you to" with the part after to being the
  part that comes before を

Comment: Is "sometimes" a typo there?

Comment: @sazarando it's a quote from the OP

Comment: Oh, right. I see that now. I should read more carefully ;P

Answer (score 3):

> インドの文化・に・詳{くわ}しい・友達を、・今度・ご紹介{しょうかい}します。

- インドの文化 - the culture of India
- ~ に詳しい - to know a lot about/be very familiar with something
- 今度 - "this time" or "next time" (depending on context)
- ご紹介します - to introduce

Possible translation:

> "Next time I'll introduce you to a friend of mine who knows a lot about Indian culture."

The comma there is just a pause; no special meaning.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few things going on here.

インドの文化にくわしい友達 : Just remember the pattern ~に+Adj meaning "adj with" or "adj at".  So, this would be "my friend who is familiar/skilled with Indian Culture".

今度: This was pretty foreign (pun intended) to me when I first started.  Almost without fail you can translate this as "next time".  Conversely, 今回 would have more immediacy - as in an episode or exchange currently happening.  Depends on context but those are a good rule of thumb.

So, putting it all together is something like:
Next time, I'll introduce you to my friend who is familiar with Indian culture.

Comment: Agreed about 今度 feeling weird at first. Relevant question: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9584